# creating a function to do standard DELETEs using prepared statments and php

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I am currently going through a nettuts.com tutorial on building a twitter clone and there they have a function for deleting rows from a database and they are using the query method but i tried converting the function to a prepared statement.However I get the  `Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined` error.Here is the code for the function

```
public function delete($table, $arr){
    $query = "DELETE FROM " . $table;
    $pref = "WHERE ";

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $query .= $pref. $key . " = " . ":" . $key;
        $pref = "AND ";
    }
    $query .= ";";
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($arr);
}

$connect = new Model();

$connect->delete("ribbits", array("user_id" => 2,
                                "ribbit" => "trial ribbit"
                                ));
```

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?Thank you!

Comment: The keys in the array passed to `execute` need to be prepended with `:`.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1014

Comment: you may want to look at your declaration of AND too what happens if its an OR :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass your array to `->execute()`, the keys need to have the `:` character before them (just like they appear in the SQL query).

So, in your `delete` function, build the SQL query like this:

```
public function delete($table, $arr){
    $keys = array();
    $values = array();

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        $keys[] = $key . " = :" . $key;
        $values[":".$key] = $value;
    }

    $query = "DELETE FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $keys);
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly but i am having some trouble understanding the code i think i have to read it a couple more times :)

Comment: @Brock90: I just simplified what you had.  What's confusing you?  Instead of using `$pref = "AND ";`, I made an array, and used `implode()` to glue the strings together.

Comment: yes now i understand what you did and its much better thanks!

Comment: can i just ask one thing? what does the `$values[":".$key] = $value;` do i mean i can see that i have to execute(":$key => $value"...) but that part is still confusing me:S

Comment: @Brock90: That is setting a key in the array `$values` to a value.  When you call `execute`, the array's keys need to start with `:` (just like in the SQL query).  `":".$key` prepends `:` to the string, then `$values[":".$key]` sets that key in the array.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87

Comment: ah! ok after reading the manual and your comment I understand it much better now thank you!